# Roadmap for Workbench?

Tags: workbench, security

Workbench 2.0 was an extremely useful tool for Mathematica Developers.  I received an early release of Workbench 3.0 to work through debugging issues encountered with Mathematica 10 and Workbench 2.0.

The early release of Workbench 3.0 had some issues but was usable.  I was wondering if there are any news or information on release data of Workbench 3.0 and a future roadmap.  I would also be interested if there will continue to be a stand-alone Mathematica.

My company works with multiple projects where Mathematica may be used in the future.  However, we are contractually obligated to not expose some data to The Internet under any circumstances. Use of other datasets require that systems pass well documented Security Guidelines (STIGs).  A stand-alone capability in this aspect is crucial.

Would like to see a detailed roadmap (if possible) to aid us with project planning.

Comment: This is not an official Wolfram Research website, so you will not receive an answer here.  Most people here are just users like you and even the few Wolfram employees who post here won't be able to speak for the company.  Best thing would be to contact Wolfram directly: http://www.wolfram.com/company/contact/

Comment: There is a post at community on this. Please see [Is there going to be a Workbench update for Mathematica 10?](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/291822)

Comment: Thanks most kindly - I will consult the links above.